# detect if div is not visible in browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect if  is not visible in browser window for an interactive map i am building. if the div is not visible I will show a popup saying "this way" or something like that. The main issue is detecting when the div is not visible in the document window.

Comment: Do you mean invisible as in "not in the viewport" or as in "hidden (css)". I've a feeling that people are misunderstanding this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I gather from your question is you want to detect if a div can be seen on the visible portion of the screen, NOT whether it's visible based upon its CSS (display, visibility).

If so, you need to determine the div's offset, then check if that's within the bounds of either the document dimensions, or another element's dimensions.

Something like this (assuming you're using jQuery)...

```
var div_offset = $('#div').offset();

if( div_offset.top < $(document).height() &&
    div_offset.left < $(document).width() ) {
    // div is within window bounds
}
```

This is a very basic example.  You would of course need to factor in how much of the div element you would want to showing for it to be considered "visible"... the above code would be true even if only the single top/left pixel of the div sits within the document bounds.  Do this by perhaps testing if the bottom right corner is showing by adding the width/height to the offset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is` function with `:visible`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NkKMv/1/)**

```
if($('#divId').is(':visible'))
{
     alert("div is visible");
}
else
{
     alert("div is not visible");
}
```

or

```
if($('#divId :visible').length)
{
     alert("div is visible");
}
else
{
     alert("div is not visible");
}
```

Comment: You can, but it has nothing whatsoever to do with whether the div is visible in the *viewport*, just if it's visible anywhere in the *document*. From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/): *"Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document."*

Answer (score 1):

You can check as follows:

```
if (document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility == 'hidden'){
//
}else{
//
}
```

Comment: That doesn't check that the element is visible. For instance, if a CSS rule containing `visibility: hidden` is applied to the element, `style.visibility` will **not** be `'hidden'`. `style` only relates to the styles applied *directly* to the element (not by rules). Also, there are lots of other ways to not be visible (`display: none`, for instance). And I'm fairly certain the OP is asking about whether the element is visible *in the viewport*.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use like this without "is"

```
     // check if div is visible
     $("div:visible").click(function () {
        alert("hello to all");
       });

     // check if div is hidden
     $("div:hidden").show("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the element is visible in viewport you can use [InView](https://github.com/opuu/InView)

Install it with npm :

```sh
npm install @opuu/inview
```

Use it like this :

```js
// import it
import InView from "@opuu/inview";


// select elements to track
let elements = new InView(".selector");

// add enter event listener
elements.on("enter", (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    // do something on enter
});

// add exit event listener
elements.on("exit", (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    // do something on exit
});
```

*Note: I wrote this package.*